# SQL Server instance level action tracking

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

How can we track actions happening at instance level in SQL Server 2014 .e.g. would like to know who created database, who changed recovery model, who setup backup strategy, who gave permissions to particular user etc..

Is there any native way or external tool effective for this scenario. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Actions happening at the instance level can be monitored by one of the following:

1. SQL Server Audit feature

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions?view=sql-server-ver15

`DATABASE_CHANGE_GROUP` - who created database
`SERVER_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP` - who gave server-level permissions to particular login
`DATABASE_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP` - who gave database-level permissions to particular user
... etc

2. Extended Events feature

Provides some additional benefits and is highly configurable, allows to track 1000+ different kind of events and will cover most your needs

3. DDL and Logon triggers

Comment: Isn't SQL Server Audit based on XE, not the other way around?

Comment: absolutely right! thanks alroc!

Answer (score 0):

You can check [DDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15) triggers. The `DDL` ones have [eventdata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-eventdata-function?view=sql-server-ver15) function which can give you details about the changes performed. The logon triggers basically are triggered when session is established with an instance of SQL Server, so it will be pretty easy to record in a table who was on-line when some settings was changed - you will be able to limit the circle of users. Make sure you are logging the data in way that is not allowed for other users to change.

Comment: I believe at instance level [CDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Change  tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) is what should be used, Logon Trigger only would help for logins.

Comment: @Shanky For sure, but it is very easy to setup. If you know that 3 of X users have logged after 21:00 and something was change during the night, it will be helpful.